# CORS error from one component, but not others

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs, firebase, azure

I have an application that is .NET Core 3.1.3, with React 16, and when I make calls to the API in production (Azure / Firebase) I get a CORS error from one specific component.

In most of the app, everything works perfectly, the base url for all of the axios calls is set in a single file, and all post requests go through a single method of the rootHttp class.

```
    addItem(model, data){
      return axios.post(
          this.rootUrl + '/' + model, data, {headers: this.headers}
      );
    }
    //Posts new item to API
```

All of the API calls seem to be functioning perfectly, except for the POST call from the employee component:

```
export function addEmployee(employee, callback){
    employee = prepEmployeeValues(employee);
    return dispatch =>{
        http.addItem("employee", employee)
            .then(addedEmployee =>{
                dispatch(addEmployeeToState(addedEmployee.data));
                callback();
            });
    }
}
//Posts new employee to API
```

Which triggers these two errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://procmanagement.azurewebsites.net/api/3/employee' 
    from origin 'https://scheduleanddirection.firebaseapp.com' 
    has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
    header is present on the requested resource.
```

and

```
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at e.exports (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.p.onerror (xhr.js:83)
```

The request headers are identical to a successful POST call from any other component. Notably the GET from the Employee component returns an empty array, and should initially return an array of 1 Employee Object, the owner, who is added when the account is registered(which works in the dev server).

The back end should receive the post here for Employees:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddEmployee(int userId, EmployeeForCreationDto employeeForCreation)
        {
            EmployeeIdIncrement employeeIdIncrement = await _repo.GetEmployeeIdForIncrement(userId);
            employeeIdIncrement.employeeId = employeeIdIncrement.employeeId + 1;

            var creator = await _userRepo.GetUser(userId);

            if (creator.Id != int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value))
                return Unauthorized();

            var employee = _mapper.Map<Employee>(employeeForCreation);

            employee.User = creator;

            employee.EmployeeId = employeeIdIncrement.employeeId;

            _repo.Add(employee);

            if (await _repo.SaveAll())
            {
                var employeeToReturn = _mapper.Map<EmployeeForReturnDto>(employee);
                return CreatedAtRoute("GetEmployee", new {employeeId = employee.EmployeeId, userId = userId }, employeeToReturn);
            }

            throw new Exception("Creation of Employee failed on save");

        }
```

An example of a successful counterpart:

Send:

```
export function addDepartment(department, callback){
    department = prepDepartmentValues(department);
    return dispatch =>{
        http.addItem("department", department)
            .then(addedDepartment =>{
                dispatch(addDepartmentToState(addedDepartment.data));
                callback();
            });
    }
}
//Posts new department to API
```

Receive:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddDepartment(int userId, DepartmentForCreationDto departmentForCreation)
        {
            var creator = await _userRepo.GetUser(userId);

            if (creator.Id != int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value))
                return Unauthorized();

            var department = _mapper.Map<Department>(departmentForCreation);

            department.User = creator;

            _repo.Add(department);

            if (await _repo.SaveAll())
            {
                var jobToReturn = _mapper.Map<DepartmentForCreationDto>(department);
                return CreatedAtRoute("GetDepartment", new {deptName = department.DeptName, userId = userId }, jobToReturn);
            }

            throw new Exception("Creation of Department failed on save");

        }
```

Everything including the Employee component works fine in the dev server, and everything but the Employee component works in production.

CORS Policy:

```
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("ProdCors",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins("https://scheduleanddirection.firebaseapp.com", "https://scheduleanddirection.web.app")
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowCredentials();
                    }
                );
            });
```

Comment: Not all requests *need* CORS, some (like GETs) are "simple". See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS.

Comment: PUTs from other components for instance are successful though, and the source url is the same in the request headers, as is the token being passed

Comment: Please give a [mre] with the two most similar requests with different behaviour, then, and show the CORS configuration for your server.

Comment: It would be difficult to reproduce, as it is only occurring in production, however if you look above, you will see the addEmployee function, which is an action that makes use of the addItem helper method above it, and is received by the AddEmployee controller method and is unsuccessful giving the errors shown.

The addDepartment function, which uses the same addItem helper method is successful, and is received by the AddDepartment controller method.

I've added the CORS policy at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much deliberation, I was able to find that it was not in fact a CORS issue that was giving me that error.

I checked the API with Postman and found that I was getting an internal server error, and then connected my Dev server API to the Production database, where I discovered that the issue was with the way that MS SQL Server works compared to SQLite.

The Dev server uses SQLite. MS SQL Server was having issues with two things that worked in SQLite:

1. Updating multiple pieces of data at a time without a explicit permission. This was addressed by adding "MultipleActiveResultSets=True" to my connection string.
2. Explicitly defining a primary key of an item with a single primary key (as opposed to a composite key). This was addressed by removing the EmployeeIdForIncrement Model entirely, and adding EmployeeIdForIncrement as an attribute of the user model.